# How to delete django model User in multi databases?

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example, I have a project (mysite) with two apps (myapp, myapp2). These apps use different databases:

settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "root",
        "PORT": "5432",
        "NAME": "test",
    },
    "test": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "root",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "NAME": "test",
    },
}
```

Then I write a databases router:

```py
from django.conf import settings


class AppRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return settings.APP_DB_MAPPER.get(model._meta.app_label)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return settings.APP_DB_MAPPER.get(model._meta.app_label)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db1 = settings.APP_DB_MAPPER.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
        db2 = settings.APP_DB_MAPPER.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
        if db1 and db2:
            if db1 == db2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in settings.APP_DB_MAPPER:
            return db == settings.APP_DB_MAPPER[app_label]
        return None
```

Then apply it.

settings.py:

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["mysite.app_router.AppRouter"]

APP_DB_MAPPER = {"myapp": "default", "myapp2": "test"}
```

Add a model in each app:

myapp/models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestDefault(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

myapp2/models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestApp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

After migrating, these tables are created:

mysql("test" db):

```
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_test             |
+----------------------------+
| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user                  |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_migrations          |
| django_session             |
| myapp2_testapp             |
+----------------------------+
```

postgres("default" db):

```
+----------+----------------------------+--------+----------+
| Schema   | Name                       | Type   | Owner    |
|----------+----------------------------+--------+----------|
| public   | auth_group                 | table  | postgres |
| public   | auth_group_permissions     | table  | postgres |
| public   | auth_permission            | table  | postgres |
| public   | auth_user                  | table  | postgres |
| public   | auth_user_groups           | table  | postgres |
| public   | auth_user_user_permissions | table  | postgres |
| public   | django_admin_log           | table  | postgres |
| public   | django_content_type        | table  | postgres |
| public   | django_migrations          | table  | postgres |
| public   | django_session             | table  | postgres |
| public   | myapp_testdefault          | table  | postgres |
+----------+----------------------------+--------+----------+
```

then I try to test relationships in shell:

```py
from mysite.myapp.models import TestDefault
from mysite.myapp2.models import TestApp
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create(username="1")  # in default db
TestDefault.objects.create(name="123",user=user)

user = User.objects.using("test").create(username="1")  # in test db
TestApp.objects.create(name="123",user=user)

# then try to delete user in test db
user.delete()  # error!
```

traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute(self, query, args)
     70             # args is None means no string interpolation
---> 71             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
     72         except Database.OperationalError as e:

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    208         assert isinstance(query, (bytes, bytearray))
--> 209         res = self._query(query)
    210         return res

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _query(self, q)
    314         self._result = None
--> 315         db.query(q)
    316         self._do_get_result(db)

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query(self, query)
    225             query = bytes(query)
--> 226         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    227 

ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test.myapp_testdefault' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-da112720c459> in <module>
----> 1 user.delete()

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in delete(self, using, keep_parents)
    916 
    917         collector = Collector(using=using)
--> 918         collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)
    919         return collector.delete()
    920 

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py in collect(self, objs, source, nullable, collect_related, source_attr, reverse_dependency, keep_parents)
    221                     if self.can_fast_delete(sub_objs, from_field=field):
    222                         self.fast_deletes.append(sub_objs)
--> 223                     elif sub_objs:
    224                         field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)
    225             for field in model._meta.private_fields:

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __bool__(self)
    276 
    277     def __bool__(self):
--> 278         self._fetch_all()
    279         return bool(self._result_cache)
    280 

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all(self)
   1240     def _fetch_all(self):
   1241         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1242             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   1243         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1244             self._prefetch_related_objects()

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__(self)
     53         # Execute the query. This will also fill compiler.select, klass_info,
     54         # and annotations.
---> 55         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
     56         select, klass_info, annotation_col_map = (compiler.select, compiler.klass_info,
     57                                                   compiler.annotation_col_map)

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql(self, result_type, chunked_fetch, chunk_size)
   1098             cursor = self.connection.cursor()
   1099         try:
-> 1100             cursor.execute(sql, params)
   1101         except Exception:
   1102             # Might fail for server-side cursors (e.g. connection closed)

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute(self, sql, params)
     97         start = time()
     98         try:
---> 99             return super().execute(sql, params)
    100         finally:
    101             stop = time()

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute(self, sql, params)
     65 
     66     def execute(self, sql, params=None):
---> 67         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
     68 
     69     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers(self, sql, params, many, executor)
     74         for wrapper in reversed(self.db.execute_wrappers):
     75             executor = functools.partial(wrapper, executor)
---> 76         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
     77 
     78     def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     82                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 
     86     def _executemany(self, sql, param_list, *ignored_wrapper_args):

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     87                 if dj_exc_type not in (DataError, IntegrityError):
     88                     self.wrapper.errors_occurred = True
---> 89                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
     90 
     91     def __call__(self, func):

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     82                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     83             else:
---> 84                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     85 
     86     def _executemany(self, sql, param_list, *ignored_wrapper_args):

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute(self, query, args)
     69         try:
     70             # args is None means no string interpolation
---> 71             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
     72         except Database.OperationalError as e:
     73             # Map some error codes to IntegrityError, since they seem to be

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    207 
    208         assert isinstance(query, (bytes, bytearray))
--> 209         res = self._query(query)
    210         return res
    211 

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _query(self, q)
    313         db = self._get_db()
    314         self._result = None
--> 315         db.query(q)
    316         self._do_get_result(db)
    317         self._post_get_result()

~/projects/learn-some/learn-some-django/test/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query(self, query)
    224         if isinstance(query, bytearray):
    225             query = bytes(query)
--> 226         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    227 
    228     def _bytes_literal(self, bs):

ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test.myapp_testdefault' doesn't exist")
```

It shows that django try to find the record in the table `testdefault` which is in the `test` database. It's obviously impossible. Why does it try to do it? What is the right way to delete a user in this situation？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the database for deletion with the `using` argument when deleting with the model's `delete()` method.

Here is where the confusion can come from:

The **queryset's** `delete` method does not accept any arguments, as shown in the docs:

> [delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#delete)
>
> Performs an SQL delete query on all rows in the QuerySet and returns
> the number of objects deleted and a dictionary with the number of
> deletions per object type.

But the **model's** `delete` method accepts the `using` argument:

> [Model.delete(using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, keep_parents=False)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects)
>
> Issues an SQL DELETE for the object. This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields. This method returns the number of objects deleted and a dictionary with the number of deletions per object type.

I hope this helps anyone who finds themselves a bit confused in the same situation: multiple DBs with active DB routers and seemingly wrong things getting deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for the delayed response. As you say, `Model.delete` can fix it. But [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-to-delete-from) says that django should delete the right record, it may be a bug in django. Several years passed, I'm no longer working on it. I will look under the hood when I have the time.